# How to set a result of an SQL query into a variable in Java

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I have a query that looks like that:

```
SELECT db_name, verb, COUNT(*) 
FROM request 
GROUP BY db_name, verb
```

The result is this:

[image: Query result]

I would like to have the results as a `List<String> result`, or ideally, as a `List<Request> result` of an entity with fields:

```
String db_name;
String verb;
int count;
```

Is there any boilerplate to do this?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways to go, in broad strokes:

### ORM / Persistence library

There is a standard (JPA) and a few implementations of this standard, most notably [Hibernate](https://hibernate.org).

The best way to think about hibernate is that it is **not** SQL based. It is a way to persist objects to permanent storage (where and how? Best not hardcode into your app specific reliance on the how), and has its own query language that has nothing to do with SQL and is considerably less powerful, but considerably simpler to use from java. It is significantly harder to optimize for major loads. But it is far, far better integrated into java. You can just... take objects, any objects - and store them. And then query them later. It also gives you DB engine independece. Yes, 'under the hood', this does use relational databases to make it all work.

You can alternatively think about hibernate as an advanced tool to attempt to automagically (and that term applies here) map SQL tables to java objects and back again, adding a veneer of db independence, but this is **not recommended**. The learning curve of figuring out what hibernate (HQL) queries end up running which SQL and how that interacts with the particulars of your flavour of DB engine is *astronomical*, and you end up spending a day just trying to wrangle hibernate into building precisely the SQL query you really wanted for performance or index or whatnot reasons. That's why it's better not to think about hibernate as an SQL abstraction - it can do that, but it is a *very* complicated tool.

You should in general move away from SQL-centric thinking if you use hibernate. Think objects and queries for them. e.g. using a lot of joins, selecting expressions (`SELECT YEARS(dob, signup) < 18 AS signedUpAsMinor FROM ...` for example), using windowing functions, SQL arrays, postgres's JSON support, etc - none of these are good ideas in hibernate.

### SQL abstractions

In contrast to hibernate, there are libraries that do not shy away from SQL and which are, as a consequence, much easier to understand: If you know what SQL you want, just, put that in. If you want to use windowing functions, go ahead.

These libraries suck if you:

- Need DB independence.
- Are unfamiliar with SQL or don't like writing it.
- Really just need to store a bunch of objects and query them back later - no particular performance or big data needs.

but are fantastic if you:

- Know what SQL to run
- Need performance tweakage
- You like 'thinking' in terms of queries. You prefer to just write one query that does what you want, instead of writing java code that uses a couple of simple queries to do what you want.

There is no spec, but there's [JOOQ](https://www.jooq.org) and [JDBI](https://www.jdbi.org) - both give you easy options to 'marshall' a `ResultSet` object into a iterable or streamable sequence of some java POJO, and you can guide exactly how the resultset is translated into instances, with sane defaults.

### Raw JDBC

Write your own code, in JDBC. This is boneheaded, in a word. JDBC is a really crappy API for end users - it is extremely old, and designed primarily to be capable of exposing all the features any major DB engine (or any DB engine that was considered major in the past 25 years), even exotic ones, and to let you squeeze out every drop of performance, because it is intended as the lowest 'glue' layer. Trying to do retry based (serialize transaction isolation level) stuff in JDBC is very difficult, even writing simple queries takes way more code than you intended and is hard to read, and there is absolutely no support whatsoever for marshalling POJOs into or out of the DB for simple cases.

As a low-level glue layer, JDBC is doing a decent job. But as an API for 'end users' writing software that interacts with DBs? No good.

I **strongly** recommend against just doing this on straight JDBC. Pick one of the other two options.

### Closing thoughts

I recommend the JOOQ/JDBI route but that's a personal preference. Good luck with the project!

Comment: Thanks for a great answer.
Finally, I went with a native query in my repository

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is by using ORM (Object-relational mapping) like hibernate but in pure java, you should serialize and deserialize by yourself.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate?